# Semantic UI dropdown multi-select removes value on refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, semantic-ui

I'm using `ajax` to bind partial view in a `div#demo` and initiating `dropdown` on `ajaxstop`.

After submitting the details, ajax loads partial view again to refresh the table section, and then re-initiating `dropdown` on `ajaxstop`.

this works fine for single selection dropdown, but multi-select dropdown reset the selected value.

I don't want multi-select dropdown to reset it's value.

```js
// partial views

var viewA = `
<select class="ui dropdown">
  <option value="">Select Single Car</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<select class="ui dropdown" Multiple>
  <option value="">Select Multiple Car</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<button type="button" class="ui button primary">Submit</button>
`

var viewB = `<table class="ui celled table unstackable">
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Job</th>
  </tr></thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td data-label="Name">James</td>
      <td data-label="Age">24</td>
      <td data-label="Job">Engineer</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-label="Name">Jill</td>
      <td data-label="Age">26</td>
      <td data-label="Job">Engineer</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-label="Name">Elyse</td>
      <td data-label="Age">24</td>
      <td data-label="Job">Designer</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>`


$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
  $(".dropdown").dropdown({
    useLabels: false,
  });
});


function bindViewA() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"
  });
  $("#viewA").html(viewA);
}

function bindViewB() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"
  });
  $("#viewB").html(viewB);
}

$(document).on('click', 'button', () => {
  bindViewB();
});


bindViewA();
bindViewB();
```

```css
#demo {
  padding: 30px;
}

#viewA {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>

<div id="demo">
  <div id="viewA"></div>
  <div id="viewB"></div>
</div>
```

Steps to reproduce.

1. Select item from both dropdowns
2. Click on Submit button to reload details section

Comment: It seems to me like a bug.

Comment: can you try `$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
  $(".dropdown").dropdown('setting', 'useLabels', false);
}); `

Comment: @Maramal Yeah it seems bug, but can't find any solution

Comment: @AbhishekPandey MIght be you are looking for ` $(".dropdown").dropdown('setting', 'useLabels', false);`

Comment: @yogendarji I saw your solution, I'm using few more parameters with `'useLabels', false`, lemme try your solution into my project.

Comment: yep, that worked. Still, if you still want to use I suggest to create an issue here: https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/

Comment: @Maramal yeah I have already posted an [issue](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/6913) on github

Comment: @AbhishekPandey did it work with other parameters also?

Comment: @yogendarji Yup it's working with other parameters, check [here](https://jsfiddle.net/0e2Lo3vu/), post your answer

Comment: @AbhishekPandey answer posted below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the dropdown without `initialize` using `setting` like below

```
$(".dropdown").dropdown('setting', {
    useLabels: false,`
})'
```

```js
// partial views

var viewA = `
<select class="ui dropdown">
  <option value="">Select Single Car</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<select class="ui dropdown" Multiple>
  <option value="">Select Multiple Car</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<button type="button" class="ui button primary">Submit</button>
`

var viewB = `<table class="ui celled table unstackable">
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Job</th>
  </tr></thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td data-label="Name">James</td>
      <td data-label="Age">24</td>
      <td data-label="Job">Engineer</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-label="Name">Jill</td>
      <td data-label="Age">26</td>
      <td data-label="Job">Engineer</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-label="Name">Elyse</td>
      <td data-label="Age">24</td>
      <td data-label="Job">Designer</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>`




$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
  $(".dropdown").dropdown('setting', {
    useLabels: false,
    forceSelection: false,
    sortSelect: true,
    //clearable: true,
    fullTextSearch: true,
    onHide: function() {
      //cleanDdlOnHide(this);
    }
  });
});

function bindViewA() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"
  });
  $("#viewA").html(viewA);
}

function bindViewB() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"
  });
  $("#viewB").html(viewB);
}

$(document).on('click', 'button', () => {
  bindViewB();
});


bindViewA();
bindViewB();
```

```css
#demo {
  padding: 30px;
}

#viewA {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>

<div id="demo">
  <div id="viewA"></div>
  <div id="viewB"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be fixed in the community fork https://fomantic-ui.com

So try to change the css + js accordingly

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fomantic-ui@2.8.3/dist/semantic.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fomantic-ui@2.8.3/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>
```

I prepared a working jsfiddle using your code here https://jsfiddle.net/sezL041k/

Comment: I'm using semantic in a huge application, I'm afraid of chain failure after replacing this with existing plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I have not found the expected behavior of the `dropdown` function in `semantic`. However, you can make do with a little patch on the `ajaxStop` function:

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
  var psel = [];
  $(".dropdown [multiple]").each(function(){
    psel.push($(this).val());
  });
  $(".dropdown").dropdown({
    useLabels: false
  });
  $(".dropdown [multiple]").each(function(){
    $(this).val(psel[0]).trigger('change');
    psel.shift();
  });
});
```

This should work even if there are several multiple dropdowns, as long as they are always selected by jquery in the same order. If not, you can always make `psel` a hash and give each multiple selector an `id`.

Comment: I have already tried this with `set selected method` of semantic ui, the problem is that ddl clears on any ajax call that happens on page, and I have more than 150 partial views in my project.